# How to clear out session on log out

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-session

I redirect the user to the login page when user click log out however I don't think it clears any application or session because all the data persisted when the user logs back in.

Currently the login page has a login control and the code behind on the page is only wired up the login Authenticate.

Can someone direct me to a good tutorial or article about handling log in and out of ASP.NET web sites?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
Session.Abandon()
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524310.aspx

Here is a little more detail on the `HttpSessionState` object:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate_members.aspx

Comment: I try Session.Abandon but it still not clearing out the session.

Comment: Something strange is happening, because Session.Abandon() should give the user a new session. Maybe you have a different problem, if you find more/better data: post it and I'm sure the community will try to help out.

Answer (score 35):

I use following to clear session and clear `aspnet_sessionID`:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ""));
```

Comment: +1 for this: Very good answer, it is the only clean way to do it. WIthout setting ASP.NET_SessionId to empty string the old session ID would still be used (which can be verified with developer toolbar F12, Network, Details). I've tried it before with only `.Clear` and `.Abandon`, but this 3rd step is really needed.

Answer (score 21):

I would prefer `Session.Abandon()`

`Session.Clear()` will not cause End to fire and further requests from the client will not raise the Session Start event.

Answer (score 14):

`Session.Abandon()` destroys the session and the `Session_OnEnd` event is triggered.

`Session.Clear()` just removes all values (content) from the Object. The `session with the same key` is still `alive`.

So, if you use `Session.Abandon()`, you lose that specific session and the user will get a `new session key`. You could use it for example when the user `logs out`.

Use `Session.Clear()`, if you want that the user remaining in the same session (if you don't want him to relogin for example) and reset all his session specific data.

Comment: I think this is the best answer so far.

Answer (score 3):

The way of clearing the session is a little different for .NET core. There is no `Abandon()` function.

**ASP.NET Core 1.0 or later**

```
//Removes all entries from the current session, if any. The session cookie is not removed.
HttpContext.Session.Clear()
```

[See api Reference here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.isession?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Methods)

**.NET Framework 4.5 or later**

```
//Removes all keys and values from the session-state collection.
HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear(); 

//Cancels the current session.
HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
```

[See api Reference here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate?view=netframework-4.7.1#Methods)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script runat="server">  
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {  
        Session["FavoriteSoftware"] = "Adobe ColdFusion";  
        Label1.Text = "Session read...<br />";  
        Label1.Text += "Favorite Software : " + Session["FavoriteSoftware"];  
        Label1.Text += "<br />SessionID : " + Session.SessionID;  
        Label1.Text += "<br> Now clear the current session data.";  
        Session.Clear();  
        Label1.Text += "<br /><br />SessionID : " + Session.SessionID;  
        Label1.Text += "<br />Favorite Software[after clear]: " + Session["FavoriteSoftware"];  
    }  
</script>  



<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head id="Head1" runat="server">  
    <title>asp.net session Clear example: how to clear the current session data (remove all the session items)</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
    <form id="form1" runat="server">  
    <div>  
        <h2 style="color:Teal">asp.net session example: Session Clear</h2>  
        <asp:Label   
            ID="Label1"   
            runat="server"   
            Font-Size="Large"  
            ForeColor="DarkMagenta"  
            >  
        </asp:Label>  
    </div>  
    </form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

session.abandon() will not remove the sessionID cookie from the browser. Therefore any new requests after this will take the same session ID. 
Hence, use Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", "")); after session.abandon().

Answer (score 1):

for .Net core

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Logout()
    {
        try
        {
            CookieOptions option = new CookieOptions();
            if (Request.Cookies[AllSessionKeys.AuthenticationToken] != null)
            {
                option.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                Response.Cookies.Append(AllSessionKeys.AuthenticationToken, "", option);
            }

            HttpContext.Session.Clear();
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Portal");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Session.Clear();

Comment: Session.Abandon() removes session and events.  .Clear doesn't get everything.

Answer (score -1):

Go to file **Global.asax.cs** in your project and add the following code.

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1));
        Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
    }
```

It worked for me..!
Reference link
 [Clear session on Logout MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27738174/clear-session-on-logout-mvc-4)

Comment: Just to clarify, note that this code DOES NOT clear any session data - it only discourages the user's web browser from caching data, and could have implications for performance if applied carelessly.

Comment: Not for session, just for Cache.